# how to allow unlimited post requests expressjs

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new to node js and trying to make app controls arduino which is connected to raspberry pi. using post requests to send data **“signals“** to the server **“raspberry pi“**. but the server stops responding after few requests.

is there any way to let the client to make unlimited post requests very fast?

or maybe something else better?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are overloading your server or network, I think network. It is normal if you keep spamming requests one after another that your server stops responding.

How frequent do you have to send these signals?

Could you explain a little bit more, I too find it hard to formulate my questions good.

Comment: I'm working on controlling RC car with camera attached to it using the browser on the mobile. so these singles frequent maybe 30 in a second. when the server stops I refresh the page and it works again. it's always stops after 10 requests so i don't think that is because network overload. thank you.

Comment: Could you show me the code. Do you use express for your web server?